# V8-code in another pthread brings to segfault

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

Why this code brings to SEGFAULT?:

```
int jack_process(jack_nframes_t nframes, void *arg)
{
    Local<Value> test = Local<Value>::New( Number::New(2) );
    return 0;
}
```

`jack_process` is running in another pthread. How I can do it right way? How I can run V8 code in another pthread?

Note, this code has no any segfaults.

```
int jack_process(jack_nframes_t nframes, void *arg)
{
    Local<Value> test;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: what version of v8 are you using ? In the latest version there is no New method that takes just the handle, you should pass a pointer to isolate also: this is one of the definitions: `Local<T> Local<T>::New(Isolate* isolate, Handle<T> that);`

Comment: `$ node --version`
`v0.10.24`

Comment: anyway in master thread it's works fine.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript and Node are single threaded. By running that code in another thread, you are essentially trying to run two threads of JS at the same time.

V8 allows you to run two JS instances on threads, but they need to be totally independent `Isolate` instances.

Generally C++ code written in another thread will just use standard C++ classes and variables, and then use [libuv's threading support](http://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/threads.html) via `uv_async_send`, and then the async handler in the main thread will convert the values into V8 objects for JS processing.